# (Python) How to make discord bot respond able to respond to multiple users at the same time

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py

I created a discord bot in python that runs some other code if a user sends it a message. The problem I'm having is that while the code is being run, the bot will not respond to any other messages. How can I make it so that while the bot is running code behind the scenes it can still respond to other messages?

Code looks like this:

```
from secrets import TOKEN
import discord

def code_that_takes_time():
    items = []
    for x in range(10):
        item = do_something() #get request in my case. takes 20s per iteration
        items.append(item) 
    return items


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user_message = str(message.content)
    send = message.channel.send

        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if user_message.startswith('$do'):
            result = code_that_takes_time()
            send(result)

        if user_message.startswith('hello'):
            send('hello, nice to meet you')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

I want it so that the bot can still respond to the 'hello' message  while it's running code_that_takes_time and then send the result whenever it finishes.

Thanks in advance for the help and ideas.

Comment: can you put in your question what the code of your `code_that_takes_time` file is?

Comment: @AdityaTomar it opens a headless browser in selenium, gets some info and then closes. It repeats a few times depending on user input. How do I make it so that the bot can still receive hello and reply while the selenium stuff is happening in the background?

Comment: The function needs to be `async` so that other functions can be called while it is running. So, you would define the function as `async def code_that_takes_time():`

Comment: Either rewrite your `code_that_takes_time` to be asynchronous or run it in an [executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) - that will switch it into the background

Answer (score 0):

anything that has a chance of blocking, such as your `code_that_takes_time` should ideally be written as a co-routine so that it will sleep and let other code execute while it is waiting. I'm relatively new to asyncio myself, but I believe the syntax is to use `async` on your `code_that_takes_time`, i.e.:

```
async def code_that_takes_time:
    items = []
    for x in range(10):
        item = do_something() #get request in my case. takes 20s per iteration
        items.append(item) 
    return items
```

then make sure to call it with the `await` keyword (if you try to call a coroutine normally, the call just retrieves and returns the coroutine object), e.g.:

```
#put any needed arguments in the parentheses as with a normal call
await code_that_takes_time()
```

I wish I could be more help than that, but I'm also a newb with this stuff and don't want to mislead.